# parsing elements with DOM

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I am stuck I want to parse a tiled map file, and there is one problem. I dont know how can I get x,y,width,height element, and how can I rebuild back this xml. I will be very grateful for your help.

```
  <objectgroup name="Meter">
  <object type="meter" x="3232" y="6016" width="512" height="96">
   <properties>
    <property name="id" value="1"/>
   </properties>
  </object>
```

My Java source code:

```
 public void readXml () throws ParserConfigurationException{
    File fXmlFile = new File("xml1.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println(doc.toString());
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("objectgroup");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("meter"));


    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a couple of adjustments, first you have to traverse all the childs and get all the object elements, an then get their attribute values, I know this is not an optimal solution, but will get you what you need:

```
    System.out.println("Root element :"
            + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("objectgroup");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        // for that will go for all objectGroups
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        NodeList childs = nNode.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength(); i++) {
            Node child = childs.item(i);
            if (child.getNodeName().equals("object")) {
                // check if we are evaluating an <object> element
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :"
                        + child.getNodeName());
                NamedNodeMap attrs = child.getAttributes();
                Node x = attrs.item(3), y = attrs.item(4), height = attrs
                        .item(0), width = attrs.item(2), type = attrs
                        .item(1);
                System.out.println("\n x :" + x.getNodeValue() + " | y : "
                        + y.getNodeValue() + " | height: "
                        + height.getNodeValue() + " | width: "
                        + width.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
    }
```